# Flex Spark Link Bar Background Color/Alpha

Tags: apache-flex, flash, styling

I am trying to change the background color and alpha of a link bar in a Flex/Flash 4 application.  No matter what properties I define, the background of said link bar is always white.  Please see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyHs2.png.

```
<mx:LinkBar id="lnkBar" backgroundAlpha="0" backgroundColor="black" bottom="0" itemClick="lnkBar_itemClickHandler(event)">
            <mx:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayCollection>
                    <fx:String>Resource Management</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Standard Reports</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Clear Selected State</fx:String>
                </s:ArrayCollection>
            </mx:dataProvider>
        </mx:LinkBar>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of "backgroundAlpha" or "backgroundColor", use "contentBackgroundAlpha" or "contentBackgroundColor".